# How to send Form data in Post request along with json parameter?

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

I am trying to make a Post request to build jenkins job with parameters
I search in network module and observed following form data we need to pass while making post request.
I create a dict called payload and sending it with data but i am getting 400 error.
How to send this form data in request(note there is json data as well, not sure how to send it)

form data:

```
name:user
value:foo
statusCode:303
redirectTo:.
Jenkins-Crumb:xyz
json:{"parameter": {"name": "user", "value": "foo"}, "statusCode": "303", "redirectTo": ".", "Jenkins-Crumb": "xyz"}
Submit:Build
```

code:

```
json = {"parameter": {"name": "user", "value": "foo"}, "statusCode": "303", "redirectTo": ".", "Jenkins-Crumb": "xyz"}
payload = {'json':json, 'Submit':'Build', "name": "user", "value": "foo", "statusCode": "303", "redirectTo": ".", "Jenkins-Crumb": "xyz"}
url_build_job = 'some valid and tested url'
response = requests.post(url_build_job, headers = {'Cookie':'abc'}, data= payload, proxies = Jenkins.proxyDict)
print(response)
```

Comment: First of all, what does your api expect? A `400` error generally indicates that the request could not be fulfilled due to the incorrect syntax of the request.

Comment: correct, i want ot send those form data in request, i am confused in which parameter i should send json or data because it consists of both

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send `JSON` data to an endpoint using a `HTTP POST` request, then you can do either of the following:

```
>>> import json

>>> url = 'https://api.jenkins.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Or this (the preferred way):

```
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for more details.